# Question about relative Cartier divisor.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective scheme over $S=spec A$, where A is a complete integrally closed noetherian local ring. $Y \subset X$ is a relative effective Catier divisor.

Then there exists a global section of $X$ over $S$ such that $Y$=image of this section. Is this true? 
If not then it is true in which case?
Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this question is appropriate for MO, but here is an answer.

The relative dimension, over $S$, of the image of a section equals $0$.  So, if $Y$ is the image of a section, then $X\to S$ is smooth of relative dimension $1$ at every point of $Y$.  Moreover, $Y$ then has relative degree $1$ over $S$.  Conversely, if $X\to S$ is smooth of relative dimension $1$ at every point of $Y$, and if $Y$ has relative degree $1$ over $S$, then $Y$ is the image of a section.